# Cannot find out meaning of $form in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I am following the Haskell version of the codebase of "[Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning](https://github.com/andre-artus/handbook-of-practical-logic-and-automated-reasoning-haskell/blob/master/src/ATP/Prop.hs)". What is the purpose of `$form` in the case below?

```
eval :: Formula -> (Rel -> Bool) -> Bool
eval fm v = case fm of
  [$form| ⊤ |] -> True
  [$form| ⊥ |] -> False
  [$form| ^a |] -> v a
  [$form| ¬ $p |] -> not (eval p v)
  [$form| $p ∧ $q |] -> eval p v && eval q v
  [$form| $p ∨ $q |] -> eval p v || eval q v
  [$form| $p ⊃ $q |] -> not (eval p v) || (eval q v)
  [$form| $p ⇔ $q |] -> eval p v == eval q v
  _ -> error "quantifier in prop eval"
```

The relevant OCaml code is simply:

```
let rec eval fm v =
  match fm with
    False -> false
  | True -> true
  | Atom(x) -> v(x)
  | Not(p) -> not(eval p v)
  | And(p,q) -> (eval p v) & (eval q v)
  | Or(p,q) -> (eval p v) or (eval q v)
  | Imp(p,q) -> not(eval p v) or (eval q v)
  | Iff(p,q) -> (eval p v) = (eval q v);;
```

Comment: It's Template Haskell; it uses a quasi quoter to parse the contents of the `[$form| ... |]` brackets.

Comment: `form` is a [quasiquoter](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#template-haskell-quasi-quotation) defined [here](https://github.com/andre-artus/handbook-of-practical-logic-and-automated-reasoning-haskell/blob/master/src/ATP/FormulaSyn.hs#L331). Looks like the purpose is to allow you to use the pretty notation to write logic formulas, instead of directly writing the patterns in Haskell syntax. I have no idea what the `$` does though ...

Comment: @DarthFennec you beat me to the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`form`](https://github.com/andre-artus/handbook-of-practical-logic-and-automated-reasoning-haskell/blob/640e1fa85c27c24d491bffef34e7b92eb8769e9b/src/ATP/FormulaSyn.hs#L331) is a [quasi-quoter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.14.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html#t:QuasiQuoter). Those give a way of invoking Template Haskell, to generate Haskell code from any other kind of syntax you wish, such as in this case Unicode logical formulas.

Essentially, it's just user-definable syntactic sugar: before the actual compilation, `[$form| ⊤ |]` will be resolved to the pattern `Top`, and `[$form| $p ∧ $q |]` to the pattern `And p q`, etc. – i.e. basically to the same stuff you have also in the OCaml code. Arguably this is overkill for this function, but when generating and/or matching more complicated formulas this can certainly come in handy.

That it's written `[$form|` and not just `[form|` is obsolete GHC-6 syntax. With current compilers, use the latter form.

Comment: Re: $form: By [this link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Quasiquotation),  the quasi-quote syntax has changed: 

>> Note that the syntax for quasiquotation has changed since the paper was written: in GHC 7 one writes [expr|...|] instead of [:expr|...|]. GHC 6.12 uses [$expr|...|]. <<

Comment: Ah, it's so old already. Back then I didn't know how to use TH, let alone quasi-quotes!